# vista add printer wizard reporting pcl 6 server error message

Tags: hp, printing

I'm trying to install a printer, and hp laserjet p2005d, on vista 64. The printer is attached to xp pro 32 bit, and when you try to add the printer using add wizard, it finds it easily but for some reason reports an error, coming back with 'wrong driver installed on server, reporting pcl 6 error. Please re-install driver.

I've tried moving the printer onto vista, and adding from xp, but xp also reports the exact same error. I have a couple of printers, an hp 6110 and a cp601 and both seems to be working 
perfectly.

Any ideas. It's driving me up the wall. 
thanks.
Bob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem and it's related to the way 32 bit vista prints to 64 bit vista.

What needs to happen is that two printer drivers need to be installed on the 64 bit machine,t the 32 bit printer driver and the 64 printer driver. First of all, install the 64 bit native printer driver and test all your printers to ensure they work. If you have any machines that are 32 bit, who hasn't then,

1. Open Printer Properties.
2. Click Sharing.
3. Open Addditional Drivers.
4. Select the 32 bit check box suitable for your driver.
5. The Please provide a Printer Driver window opens up.
6. Get your 32 bit printer driver into the cd, browse to it, and install.
7. Go to your machine, Click Add Printer, Browse to the share.
8. The 32 bit printer driver will be brought across and installed.

That's it. 
Bob.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with HP's PCL 6 driver for that printer.  If you installed the driver from CD, try downloading the latest PCL6 driver from HP's website and installing that on the PC hosting the printer.  If you're using the latest PCL6 driver, try switching the host PC's print driver to either HP's PCL5 driver, PostScript (PS) driver or Universal Print Driver.